# Is one-way ANOVA appropriate for comparing differences in (calendar) monthly means?

Tags: anova, mean

I have data for solute export by month (monthly mean values with year aggregated so that n=12), in one-way ANOVA the groups should be independent. A month of high solute export will probably lead to the mean of the following month also being high, however this is not always the case. Is one-way ANOVA appropriate for comparing to see if there is a statistically significant difference between months or would another measure be more appropriate? Thanks.

Comment: How many months of data have you got?

Comment: Between 224 and 320 depending on my dataset.

Comment: Then you should look into time series models.

Comment: I've aggregated months from different years, so that I have a single value for that month (n=12). Would an ANOVA test be a valid approach for comparing the means between these months in this case?

Comment: Not invalid but not ideal. Time series lets you control for other variation so that you can get a better picture of what is going on. E.g, perhaps the "best month" changed over time.

Comment: Okay thanks, I see. The different between months and the time series analysis isn't my main focus- but I was looking for a method which would corroborate 'visual inspection'